# How to set margin-left without it being inherited by child elements?

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to set the **margin-left** and **margin-right** of all contents within the page header (xsl-region-before). I've tried to add the attribute to a <fo:block> that in turn holds all the header contents. However the margin gets inherited by child blocks which is not what I want.

Is there a way to set the margin without it being inherited?

Answer (score 4):

It's my pain.
Every season when I'll start to work with XSL-FO I'll get this trouble.

The Solution. Now and forever.

1 . if you want margins on a external block (my favorite). (Thanks for Yobert.)

```
<fo:block-container
    margin-left="3pt"
    margin-right="3pt"
    >
    <fo:block-container margin="0">
```

2 . if you'll set margins on a table (I dislike to do this but I should for my team to remember). (Thanks for David Mangon.)

```
<fo:table
    margin-left="3pt"
    margin-right="3pt"
    >
    <fo:table-body
        start-indent="0"
        end-indent="0"
        >
```

3 . just for a single concrete cell in a table to override indents (<fo:block-container margin="0">). (Thanks to me.)

```
<fo:table
    margin-left="3pt"
    margin-right="3pt"
    >
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block-container margin="0">
                    ... content ...
```

4 . Also the Negative margins of Arne Evertsson (look his answer).

5 . In some weird cases. If you use a padding, then don't forget to add margin="0"

```
<fo:block-container padding="0 3pt" margin="0">
    <fo:block>
```

6 . If some troubles then think to use the Rule of thumb - don't use padding on a parent, use margins on a child element. In yours layout mastering.

```
<!-- Set borders. -->
<fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="borderDefault">
    <!-- It's like a padding on a parent. -->
    <fo:table-and-caption margin="2pt">
```

All this approaches were tested.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround: Setting the margin to a negative number in the inner block:

```
<fo:block margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-width="100%" />
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                    <fo:block margin-left="-10mm" margin-right="-10mm">
                        Some text
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following attributes on your table body element:

start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt

DMA

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using two nested `<fo:block-container>` elements.

```
<fo:block-container margin-left="1in">
<fo:block-container margin-left="0in">
...stuff...
</fo:block-container>
</fo:block-container>
```

It works since the inner block container now passes on a margin of 0 to it's children.

I haven't tried this with just `<fo:block>` but I bet it would work there too.  `<fo:block-container>` is probably what you want though.

Comment: I'm not working with this anymore so I won't be able to test any solutions or upvote/accept an answer. Let's hope someone else is helped.